# Using Xetex to Include bmp file into document using Plain TeX

Tags: graphics, xetex, plain-tex

I just installed TeX Live 2017 and am using XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit) (preloaded format=xetex 2018.12.4)  4 DEC 2018 22:30

I have a bmp file named nh-seal_3.bmp with dimensions width 1.33in by height 1.30in

The image was found and saved as a bmp image from this location:

http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/1900/1954/nh-seal_3.htm

Could someone show me how to insert this in a document using XeTeX and plain TeX coding?

I asked a similar question two years ago (asked May 1 '16 at 23:02, several answers including David Carlisle Aug 25 at 21:07) but I think the XeTeX has more features now, like \XeTexpicfile.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```
% test.tex
% xetex test.tex
\centerline{%
\XeTeXpicfile nh-seal_3.bmp width 8cm
}
\bye
```

Comment: Ran without errors but no visible graphics on the page? I bracketed the place where the graphic should be between two letters. The letters appear, with space for the graphic, but no graphic.% test.tex
% xetex test.tex
\centerline{a \XeTeXpicfile nh-seal_3_sm.bmp width 2in \relax b}
\bye
log file: This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit) (preloaded format=xetex 2018.12.4)  5 DEC 2018 11:15
entering extended mode
**./graphics-demo.tex
(graphics-demo.tex [1] )A
Output written on graphics-demo.pdf (1 page).

Comment: @GAS4: Here a graphics is visible.
Something, a bmp file itself?, may be wrong in
your case. You can obtain my result here:

(http://www.w32tex.org/toolsw32/bmp-xetex.zip)

Comment: Thank you Akira. I guess there was something wrong with the bmp file I had. --George